# Are width and float incompatible?

Tags: css

I have a website where the `navbar` is 41% width,  and `float: right`, but to make the `float: right` work, I have to remove the `width: 41%`, why? is there any incompatibility between the `width` and `float`?

```
  <header class="tab-content cabecera">
  <a class="logo pull-left" href="/">
    <img src="images/logo1.png" width="250px" alt="ziiweb"/>
  </a>
  <div class="social">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/!!!" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
    <g:plusone align="middle"></g:plusone>
  </div>
  <nav>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Qué ofrecemos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Trabajos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
```

---

```
a.logo {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 37%;
}
.social {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 21%;
}
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 41%;
}
```

Comment: seems fine for me in chrome

Comment: assigning width to `a` tag will not work until it has been given `display` property.

Comment: @Mr_Green or if it's floated, right?

Comment: @ChrisB Yes.. You must be sure :)

Answer (score 2):

No, they *are* compatible.

`nav` is indeed floating right just as you want it to, having width does not affect that. The difference you see when you remove `width:41%` is the size of the `nav` element changing, and thereby removing the space to the right of the `ul` inside of it.

**There are three ways to correct this**

1. Float the `ul` inside of `nav` to the right by adding `float:right` to your `.nav` rule
2. Change the width of `nav` to match the width of the `ul` inside of it.
3. Remove the width property on `nav`

[image: nav element]

[image]

See how `ul.nav` is the same width as `nav` and the items in the `ul` are on the left side of `nav`? Doing one of the things I've listed above will cause the items to show up closer to the right side as I believe you are intending.

**Example of correction #1 (Float .nav to the right)**

[image]

[image]